# Apache Shiro: redirect me to login page

Tags: security, spring-security, java-ee-6, shiro

When I try to access some protected page like the writerPage, Shiro keep redirecting me to the loging Page

[image: project]

This is the shiro.ini file

```
[users]
admin = p
mike = p, reader, writer
joe = p, writer 


[urls]
/success/** = authc
/writer/** = authc
```

And the server show some error:

```
    INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/ShiroTest3_mvn] ServletContext.log():Cleaning up Shiro Environment
    INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/ShiroTest3_mvn] ServletContext.log():Initializing Shiro environment
    GRAVE: 105 [http-thread-pool-4848-(1)] INFO org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader - Starting Shiro environment initialization.

    GRAVE: 997 [http-thread-pool-4848-(1)] INFO org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader - Shiro environment initialized in 882 ms.

    INFO: Loading application com.mycompany_ShiroTest3_mvn_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT at /ShiroTest3_mvn
    INFO: com.mycompany_ShiroTest3_mvn_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT was successfully deployed in 1 606 milliseconds.
```

And this the web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
        30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Do i need to add/modify something?

Though Shiro seems to be less complicated for a beginner compared to Spring Security, It seems it has less support :(

UPDATE

after adding the [main] code:

I get this error

server log error

```
    INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Shiro environment
    GRAVE: 3155 [admin-thread-pool-4848(1)] INFO org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader - Starting Shiro environment initialization.

    GRAVE: 4218 [admin-thread-pool-4848(1)] ERROR org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader - Shiro environment initialization failed

    GRAVE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.<init>(ConvertUtilsBean.java:157)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.<init>(BeanUtilsBean.java:117)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:68)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ContextClassLoaderLocal.get(ContextClassLoaderLocal.java:153)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getInstance(BeanUtilsBean.java:80)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getInstance(PropertyUtilsBean.java:114)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtils.java:460)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.isTypedProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:248)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:491)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applySingleProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:203)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:164)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:124)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:170)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:97)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123)
        at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createWebSecurityManager(IniWebEnvironment.java:203)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.configure(IniWebEnvironment.java:99)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:92)
        at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
        at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:226)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:138)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 69 more

    GRAVE: PWC1306: Startup of context /ShiroTest3_mvn failed due to previous errors
    GRAVE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5571)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:527)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5384)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

    GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.<init>(ConvertUtilsBean.java:157)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.<init>(BeanUtilsBean.java:117)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:68)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ContextClassLoaderLocal.get(ContextClassLoaderLocal.java:153)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getInstance(BeanUtilsBean.java:80)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getInstance(PropertyUtilsBean.java:114)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtils.java:460)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.isTypedProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:248)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:491)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applySingleProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:203)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:164)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:124)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:170)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:97)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123)
        at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createWebSecurityManager(IniWebEnvironment.java:203)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.configure(IniWebEnvironment.java:99)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:92)
        at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
        at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:226)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:138)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
        ... 39 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 69 more

    ATTENTION: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

    GRAVE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
    java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

    GRAVE: Exception while loading the app
    GRAVE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

Comment: Well this is kind of Weird, I just replaced the authc to authcBasic and it work :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `authc` filter is a [FormAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/trunk/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/FormAuthenticationFilter.java) by default.  Because it expects a form to exist, you must configure the form's url.

But you have to configure that login URL in two places, one in `[main]` and another in `[urls]`:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.successUrl = /success/successLogin.jsp

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/success/** = authc
/writer/** = authc
```

- The first line in `[main]` says "The authentication filter should use the following login URL when redirecting a user to login"
- The first line in `[urls]` says: "Whenever a request for the /login.jsp url comes in, I want the `authc` filter to handle the request".

They are separate, but complementary config statements - both need to be specified for the FormAuthenticationFilter to work.

when you changed to `authcBasic`, this worked because there is no form to process - the browser supplies the login dialog so Shiro doesn't have to look for form parameters.

Comment: Thank You for your help, I have found that solution from Balusc Tutorial BUT, once I add the code in the [main] It dont even run, it give me errors. I have updated the post with the GlassFish server log.

Comment: You need to include the `jcl-over-slf4j` `.jar` file in your classpath (as well as one of the SLF4J logging implementations (simple, log4j, logback, etc).

Comment: Thank you, it worked after adding jcl-over-slf4j jar file, But I still have those two GRAVE warning in the first lines of the server log. Is it normal? ... I have another question, not related to the subject though: How can I add a logout?

Comment: I have try to add in the [main] part this: logout.redirectUrl  = /index.jsp and in the [url] part this: /index.jsp = logout but it dont work.

Answer (score 1):

Please include below jars in WEB-INF/lib

```
commons-beanutils-1.6.1.jar
commons-collections-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.3.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
```